# Use an input-number value as input-number max value of another field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I want to store the value of a input-number field to be used for the max value of a different input-number field.
Which is the best way to do this?
PHP, JavaScript, jQuery or whatever you want...

My own try:

```
<input id="thingsToDo" type="number" value="0">
<input id="thingsDone" type="number" value="0" onkeypress="if(thingsDone.value > thingsToDo.value) thingsDone.value = thingsToDo.value;">
```

(It doesn't even work)

Comment: What have you done / tried so far? This is a relatively simple problem, try some Googling if you haven't started yet.

Comment: I wrote my try, I wanted to find out the "best way for..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery option:

```
$('#maxedInput').on('input', function() {
    var max = $('limitInput').val();
    if ($(this).val() > max) {
        $(this).val(max);
    }
}
```